# String matching in HQL

Tags: string, filter, hql

I'm creating an HQL query to filter a grid of data:

```
string formatString = "Type = {0} AND {1} = '{2}' AND CompletedDate > '{3}' 
  AND CompletedDate < '{4}' AND UserName LIKE '{5}'";

HqlBindingSource.Where = string.Format(formatString, type, keyId, entityID, 
  fromDate, toDate, toDate, UserTextBox.Text);
```

The problem I'm having is the string matching on the UserName field.  I'm used to working with SQL and I can't get it to match on a value using = or LIKE.  Can anyone point me in the right direction for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had "toDate" listed twice, so UserTextBox.Text was never used in the query.